# Starting an app when iPhone turns on?

Tags: iphone, startup

I don't care if its something Apple wont accept but, how would I get an iPhone app to start up when the iPhone turns on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't that Apple won't accept it, but that they just won't run it. The only way to achieve this would be to jailbreak the phone and play with launchd.

Answer (score 1):

Put a plist in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ with a path to your tool, just like MacOSX.